# Certain Instance Method Cannot be Found Under DispatchQueue

Tags: swift

```
func calculator (yourName : String, theirName : String) -> String {


let score = 90

if score > 80 {
    return "Higher than 80%"
}

else {
    return "Lower than 80%"
}

return score    //Error 
}
```

Because score is not a string I get this error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'String'
```

I have seen solutions which call for the returning of values to all be in one line. However, it wouldn't work in this case because only one value needs to be returned...

How would I fix this problem?

Comment: How is this related to dispatch queues?? What do you expect the final `return score` to do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to `DispatchQueue`.

Swift is a language with a strong type system. The return type is `String` and `score` is `Int` which is a type mismatch.

You could return the string representation of the `Int`

```
return String(score)
```

However with the given logic this line will actually never be reached so just delete it.

<strike>`return score`</strike>

Answer (score 0):

You can update code as below

```
func calculator (yourName : String, theirName : String) -> String {


let score = 90

if score > 80 {
    return "Higher than 80%"
}

else {
    return "Lower than 80%"
}

return "\(score)"    //Error 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `return "\(score)"` instead of `return score` in your code.